# NSight Profiler Signal 139

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I am trying to profile my program using the inbuilt profiler in NSight but the profiling session terminates immediately after starting and I receive as feedback "Warning: Application received signal 139". What does this mean?

I also receive the following error message:

> Unable to read the entire session timeline. The displayed timeline may
>   be empty or incomplete because the application aborted or failed to
>   flush profile data before exiting. The application should call
>   cudaDeviceReset() before exiting to ensure that all profile data is
>   flushed.

Comment: It looks like a segmentation fault. Does your program work as expected and returns normally?

Comment: I checked for a segmentation fault thoroughly but the program works as expected and cuda-memcheck finds no errors. For the record, the debug module doesn't work either.

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` requires `nvcc` with the option `-g -G` to compile the code

Comment: -g and -G are used during compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nsight, go to Profile Configurations and then the Profiler tab. Uncheck "`Enable concurrent kernel profiling`".

Comment: This turned out to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Checking `Start application with profiling enabled` fixed it for me. It is on by default, but I wanted explicit control so turned it off initially. Disabling `concurrent kernel profiling` worked too, but it prevents you from profiling apps with dynamic parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

Does you program require some command line parameters?  The debugger and profiler may haven't correctly pick your CLI options from your configuration. You need the specify them in Nsight User Property, or Activity page for profiler.

Comment: Yes it does. The program takes two file names as input and tries to open them. I either get that relevant files cannot be opened when I believe the program cannot find the files or signal 139 when I believe the program does find them, depending on what I use for arguments when launching the profiling.

Comment: Xuan answer is for Nsight Visual Studio Edition. On Linux/Unix signal 139 is from a segmentation fault. The segmentation fault could be caused by your application or the profiling code injected into your application. To diagnose the problem you can add a getchar at the top of you main() function. This will pause your application. Launch the application through Visual Profiler or Nsight Profiler. Attach a debugger (gdb or eclipse gdb) to your process. Move the PC beyond the getchar(). When you get the segmentation fault gdb or eclipse will contain the callstack of the fault.

Comment: Given your feedback the most likely cause of the segmentation fault is  insufficient parameter checking and error handling around your command line arguments. I recommend you check that you are correctly specifying your command line arguments and the working directory in the profiler launch settings.

Comment: Just an observation: I'm getting the same behavior.  When run in a Linux Term window, with the same File/WorkingDir/Arguments, all is well.  When the Profiler runs it, I get the 139 msg in the middle of a calculation loop.  (Well past the param checking.)  My arguments list is 11 items long.  Selecting single-kernel profiling, prevents the 139 issue.  Maybe I need to set an env variable.